# Aligning text boxes on Laravel form

Tags: html, css

I am making my first Laravel project and I cannot seem to figure out how to align my fields. I have 2 text boxes on on line in my form but the third one is sitting below the first 2. Is there a way to have all 3 on the same line?

My code:

```
   <div style="float:left;" style="margin-left: 200px;" >
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Admin time (Hours):</label>
                    <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="admin_time" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" min="1" step="1" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3" style="margin-left: 200px;">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Work time (Hours):</label>
                  <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="work_time" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" min="1" step="1" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3" style="margin-left: 400px;">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Work time (Hours):</label>
                    <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="rest_time" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" min="1" step="1" required>
                  </div>
```

Comment: This is a css question. Take a look at css flexbox instead of floating. Are you using bootstrap? in that case take a look at the grid in the docs

Answer (score 1):

Use and learn `flexbox` instead of `float: left;`

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div>
    <label for="recipient-name">Admin time (Hours):</label>
    <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="admin_time" id="recipient-name" min="1" step="1" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="recipient-name">Work time (Hours):</label>
    <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="work_time" id="recipient-name" min="1" step="1" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="recipient-name">Work time (Hours):</label>
    <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="rest_time" id="recipient-name" min="1" step="1" required>
  </div>
<div>
```